# Handle new properties in CoreData and optional types of objective C

Tags: swift, core-data, optional-parameters

I work with CoreData and I came up with some questions that I could not answer through research. Let's assume I have developed an app and the persistent storage is done with CoreData. Now I want to update the app and add a property to an entity. I think the best solution is to make the new property optional so that there are no problems with the existing instances, do you agree? Another thing is that when I try, I noticed the int16? not allowed because it does not work with objective-c. But as an alternative, NSNumber? works, which I somehow don't like. How do you do it and what does the best practice look like?

Comment: There are many articles on migration for CoreData you are asking for more of opinions and  discussion which is out of scope for SO.

Comment: I would like to know what the best way is to put the topics mentioned into practice. Would you please share these articles when they deal with the topics mentioned, thank you.

Comment: You need to do a migration. Now, if you add that new property to an old entity, what should be its default value? If it can have a default value, set it.

Comment: @Larme Hey, that's exactly what I'm looking for. Migration is the right keyword. Thank you.